# How can i aggregate text from one table by array of id's in another?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i am using Postgresql 11.
I have two tables:

`Report_template`

| `id` (int) | `template_blocks_id` (int[]) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2,3 |
| 2 | 3,2,1 |
| 3 | 2,2,3,1 |
| 4 | 3,1 |

`Report_template_block`

| `id` (int) | `code` (text) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Block #1 |
| 2 | Block #2 |
| 3 | Block #3 |
| 4 | Block #4 |

How can I get the aggregate of all report_template_block code's indicated in the array of the report_template in the same order?

I want to get that:

| `report_template_id` | `aggregated_code` |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `"Block #1, Block #2, Block #3"` |
| 2 | `"Block #3, Block #2, Block #1"` |
| 3 | `"Block #2, Block #2, Block #3, Block #1"` |
| 4 | `"Block #3, Block #1"` |

For now i have next SQL query, but that query don't consider repeat of report_pattern_block.id:

```
SELECT report_template.id,
       (select string_agg(code, '\n')
        from report_template_block
        where id = unnest(report_template.template_blocks_id)) as generated_template
FROM report_template
```

Comment: You should normalize the database model at least to 1NF. There's an M:N relationship between those two tables, and you'll need a third table to model it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join to the result of the unnest in order to repeat the rows:

```
select rt.id as report_template_id, 
       string_agg(rtb.code, ',' order by b.idx) as aggregated_code
from report_template rt
  cross join unnest(rt.template_blocks_id) with ordinality as b(template_id, idx)
  join report_template_block rtb on rtb.id = b.template_id
group by rt.id
order by rt.id;
```